# How to get back original value after standardization in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, standardization

I am using `StandardScaler()` to standardize the inputs.
How can I convert prediction back to original data? I am using the following code, but it throws me an error.

```py
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#custom inputs for prediction after training
sample = pd.DataFrame({'salary': [1211], 'age': [30]})
sample = sc.transform(sample)
sample_predict = sc.inverse_transform(sample_predict)

print (sample_predict)
```

- shape of `X_test`: `(3000, 2)`
- shape of `sample_predict`: `(1, 2)`

Error:

```
X *= self.scale_
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,2)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, if `sample_predict` shape is `(1,2)`. I think you meant `sample`, since you are defining `sample` and transforming it before the `inverse_transform`.

Comment: @Kaveh

My code seems to be working what I have done is get mean and std dev from `y_train` samples, and used them to get back the original value of predict.

`y_train= np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1)
standardY = StandardScaler().fit(y_train)` ...


`original_values= standardY.inverse_transform(y_pred)`

I am not sure if my this is correct, do you have any idea if it's correct approach? 

thanks!

Comment: Yes.it is the correct approach. You should use the same scaler for y_train to get back prediction, to the original scale with inverse_transform. Note that it is not recommended to apply standardization on target values.

Comment: Thanks man! I think `StandardScaler().fit(y_train)` only computes the parameters, and does not perform the transformation on targets.

Comment: Yes, `fit()` only compute the parameters, and does not make any transform. for transform you may use `fit_transform()` or `transform()`